# All pairs of (a,b) of positive integers satisfying a given condition.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to determine all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers satisfying the condition $a^{b^2}=b^a$. So far i have found only one, namely $(1,1)$. How can i do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Take logarithms
2. $\log_b(a)\in\mathbb Q\Leftrightarrow \exists n\in\mathbb N:a=b^n$
3. Juggle a little with the remaining expression.